# Modal popup view like twitter and facebook in iPhone

Tags: iphone

I want to create a modal popup view which contains some UIControls
like button, image, textfield etc.

Here is an example of what I want:

[image]

What should I use?
UIAlertView or UIView or something else ...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `UIView` and just customize it. :)
`UIAlertView` has a default appearance.

Answer (score 1):

you try use REComposeViewController
https://github.com/romaonthego/REComposeViewController

Comment: I have solved this by creating my own UIView. But thanks to give answer this solution look good I may need in future.